# How to make Post-Back with UserControl ？

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to learn how to make post-back with user control.

for example;

using two text box and one button, 
use textbox input some thing then click button. adding on the page. then clear textbox content. then if u want to add new record. also input some thing, then click button, last record will be stay and new record insert below of the last record.

so how can i make it ?

using asp.net(c#)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Do you have any code? Why is this specific to a user control and not just a web form in general?

In any event you will need a control to bind the data to when the post is made and a place to store said data. DB table and data table bound to a repeater are first thoughts.

Comment: just use to one user control and one webform page, data will be stored in the memory dont need to stored DB.

Comment: what have you tried so far? code example? i am not going to write the code for you. as posted above, a repeater control or data grid could serve your needs. just rebind the data to the control on post back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add dynamic controls to the page. See this one whether it is    satisfied your requirement. This will help you to get some idea.

This is done using asp.net data grid.

http://telans.blogspot.com/2013/09/create-filter-tool-using-aspnet.html